# How to represent a field as a group with operators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, soft-question

How do you use groups with operators to represent rings or fields?

As a concrete example, how do we define the notion of a subfield using the language of groups with operators?

---

I quite like [groups with operators](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Group_with_operators) as an abstraction. Basically, it is a first-order structure whose language is $+$, the (not-necessarily-commutative) group operation and $\Omega$, a set of symbols, each of which is interpreted as an endormorphism in the group with operators.

I'm trying to get an understanding of how flexible this abstraction is and how much ability it gives you to express elementary results in abstract algebra.

A vector space over a fixed field $K$ has a nice representation in this setting. $\Omega$ is $K$ and the action of each $k$ in $\Omega$ on $G$ is $g \mapsto kg$. This also means that changing the field $K$ changes the signature of the group with operators, so two vector spaces over different fields are incomparable for *logical reasons*.

I'm confused though about this claim below.

> In practice, we deal with general groups with operators infrequently. However, many structures—groups and modules (including rings, fields, and vector spaces) )—are special cases of this general structure, and we can prove many results—for example, the Jordan-Hölder Theorem—about groups with operators in general; we then avoid repeated proofs of the same results in different fields.

Vector spaces and modules have a very clear paraphrase in the language of groups with operators.

For rings and fields though, I'm not sure how they would be represented. The trivial representation where the ring or field is $\Omega$ and the group is just $\{e\}$) is not very interesting.

Making $G$ the additive structure of the ring or field and adding the structure itself as $\Omega$ with each operator interpreted as scalar multiplication, though, seems to have another drawback.

If $K$ is a subfield of $L$, then how do we express this in the language of groups with operators?

$\mathcal{L}$ would have $L$ as its operators and $(L, +)$ as its group component.

If $K$ is a subfield, then in general $K$ can't define an interpretation for scalar multiplication by each $l$ in $L$.

We could take $\mathcal{L}$ and insist that that $\Omega$ is $K$, the subfield, yielding $\mathcal{L}_K$, or something.

That seems a little ad hoc though.

Is there a correct way to represent a field as a group with operators?

Comment: I'm afraid we can only represent the underlying vector space / module structure of a field / ring, and as such, as you observed, we can't define subfields / subrings in this setting.